# reorder pages in FragmentStatePagerAdapter using getItemPosition(Object object)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I believe that FragmentStatePagerAdapter does not behave correctly when overriding `getItemPosition(Object object)` with the purpose of reordering the pages.

Below is a simple example. In the initial state, the order of the pages is {A, B, C}. Upon calling `toggleState()`, the order of the pages changes to {A, C, B}. By overriding `getItemPosition(Object object)`, we ensure that the current page being viewed (A, B, or C) does not change.

```
public static class TestPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private boolean mState = true;

    public TestPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    private void toggleState() {
        mState = !mState;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private String getLabel(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "A";
            case 1:
                return mState ? "B" : "C";
            default:
                return mState ? "C" : "B";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        String label = ((TestFragment) object).getLabel();
        if (label.equals("A")) {
            return 0;
        } else if (label.equals("B")) {
            return mState ? 1 : 2;
        } else {
            return mState ? 2 : 1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return getLabel(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return TestFragment.newInstance(getLabel(position));
    }
}
```

I have encountered two separate behaviours which seem incorrect.

1. If I immediately call `toggleState()` (while viewing page A, before swiping to any other page), the app crashes.

   ```
   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
     at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:477)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.destroyItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:136)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:867)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:469)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:441)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dataSetChanged(ViewPager.java:766)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$PagerObserver.onChanged(ViewPager.java:2519)
     at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
     at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:276)
     at com.ugglynoodle.test.testfragmentstatepageradapter.MainActivity$TestPagerAdapter.toggleState(MainActivity.java:55)
     ...
   ```

   Looking at the source of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, this would be fixed by first checking the size of `mFragments` (as in lines 113-115) before calling `set()` in line 136.
2. If I first swipe to page B, then `getItem(2)` is called, page C is created, and `mFragments` now has a size of 3 (this will prevent the crash above from happening in a moment). Then I swipe back to page A, and page C is destroyed, as it should be (since it is 2 pages away, and I'm using the default offscreen page limit of 1). Now, I call `toggleState()`. Page B is now destroyed. However, page C is NOT recreated! This means, when I now swipe to the right, I get an empty page.

First, it would be nice to know whether I'm correct and these are in fact bugs, or whether I'm doing something wrong. If they are bugs, can anyone suggest a workaround (other than debugging and rebuilding the support library myself)? Surely somebody must have overridden `getItemPosition(Object object)` successfully (apart from setting everything to `POSITION_NONE`)?

I am using the current revision (10) of the support library.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Looking at the source of FragmentStatePagerAdapter, I figured out exactly what is going wrong. The FragmentStatePagerAdapter caches the fragments and saved states in ArrayLists: `mFragments` and `mSavedState`. But when the fragments are reordered, there's no mechanism for reordering the elements of `mFragments` and `mSavedState`. Therefore, the adapter will provide the wrong fragments to the pager.

I've filed [an issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37990) for this, and attached a fixed implementation (NewFragmentStatePagerAdapter.java) to the issue. In the fix, I've added a `getItemId()` function to FragmentStatePagerAdapter. (This mirrors the reordering implementation in FragmentPagerAdapter.) An array of the itemIds by adapter position is stored at all times. Then, in `notifyDataSetChanged()`, the adapter checks if the itemIds array has changed. If it has, then `mFragments` and `mSavedState` are reordered accordingly. Further modifications can be found in `destroyItem()`, `saveState()` and `restoreState()`.

To use this class, `getItemPosition()` and `getItemId()` must be implemented consistently with `getItem()`.

Comment: I have used your fixed implementation ,but one problem that i am facing is NO UPDATION of neighbour fragments in ViewPager.How can i fix it ?

Comment: I think you're spot on, @UgglyNoodle, I just wanted to point out that if you're ok with having the reordered fragments destroyed and recreated, returning POSITION_NONE for fragments whose order has changed and POSTION_UNCHANGED for those fragments which have not changed achieves the desired result as well without crashing.

Answer (score 1):

For me worked one of answers of [an issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37990). Answers #20 #21. Link to solution https://gist.github.com/ypresto/8c13cb88a0973d071a64.
Best solution, works for updating pages and also reordering. Only in this solution Adapter didn't throw IndexOutOfBoundsExeption when destroying item (in method destroyItem), which is known bug for other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I've reimplemented the [existing solution](https://gist.github.com/ypresto/8c13cb88a0973d071a64) in Kotlin such that it allows you to return a `String` instead of a `long` for the item id. You can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/SUPERCILEX/1e7fd5f50d38bfccaeffdf0eccda426a) or below:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Parcelable
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import java.util.HashSet
import java.util.LinkedHashMap

/**
 * A PagerAdapter that can withstand item reordering. See
 * https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36956111.
 *
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter
 */
abstract class MovableFragmentStatePagerAdapter(
        private val manager: FragmentManager
) : NullablePagerAdapter() {
    private var currentTransaction: FragmentTransaction? = null
    private var currentPrimaryItem: Fragment? = null

    private val savedStates = LinkedHashMap<String, Fragment.SavedState>()
    private val fragmentsToItemIds = LinkedHashMap<Fragment, String>()
    private val itemIdsToFragments = LinkedHashMap<String, Fragment>()
    private val unusedRestoredFragments = HashSet<Fragment>()

    /** @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.getItem */
    abstract fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment

    /**
     * @return a unique identifier for the item at the given position.
     */
    abstract fun getItemId(position: Int): String

    /** @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.startUpdate */
    override fun startUpdate(container: ViewGroup) {
        check(container.id != View.NO_ID) {
            "ViewPager with adapter $this requires a view id."
        }
    }

    /** @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem */
    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
        val itemId = getItemId(position)

        val f = itemIdsToFragments[itemId]
        if (f != null) {
            unusedRestoredFragments.remove(f)
            return f
        }

        if (currentTransaction == null) {
            // We commit the transaction later
            @SuppressLint("CommitTransaction")
            currentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction()
        }

        val fragment = getItem(position)
        fragmentsToItemIds.put(fragment, itemId)
        itemIdsToFragments.put(itemId, fragment)

        val fss = savedStates[itemId]
        if (fss != null) {
            fragment.setInitialSavedState(fss)
        }
        fragment.setMenuVisibility(false)
        fragment.userVisibleHint = false

        currentTransaction!!.add(container.id, fragment)

        return fragment
    }

    /** @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.destroyItem */
    override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, fragment: Any) {
        (fragment as Fragment).destroy()
    }

    /** @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem */
    override fun setPrimaryItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, fragment: Any?) {
        fragment as Fragment?
        if (fragment !== currentPrimaryItem) {
            currentPrimaryItem?.let {
                it.setMenuVisibility(false)
                it.userVisibleHint = false
            }

            fragment?.setMenuVisibility(true)
            fragment?.userVisibleHint = true
            currentPrimaryItem = fragment
        }
    }

    /** @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate */
    override fun finishUpdate(container: ViewGroup) {
        if (!unusedRestoredFragments.isEmpty()) {
            for (fragment in unusedRestoredFragments) fragment.destroy()
            unusedRestoredFragments.clear()
        }

        currentTransaction?.let {
            it.commitAllowingStateLoss()
            currentTransaction = null
            manager.executePendingTransactions()
        }
    }

    /** @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.isViewFromObject */
    override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, fragment: Any): Boolean =
            (fragment as Fragment).view === view

    /** @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.saveState */
    override fun saveState(): Parcelable? = Bundle().apply {
        putStringArrayList(KEY_FRAGMENT_IDS, ArrayList<String>(savedStates.keys))
        putParcelableArrayList(
                KEY_FRAGMENT_STATES,
                ArrayList<Fragment.SavedState>(savedStates.values)
        )

        for ((f, id) in fragmentsToItemIds.entries) {
            if (f.isAdded) {
                manager.putFragment(this, "$KEY_FRAGMENT_STATE$id", f)
            }
        }
    }

    /** @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.restoreState */
    override fun restoreState(state: Parcelable?, loader: ClassLoader?) {
        if ((state as Bundle?)?.apply { classLoader = loader }?.isEmpty == false) {
            state!!

            fragmentsToItemIds.clear()
            itemIdsToFragments.clear()
            unusedRestoredFragments.clear()
            savedStates.clear()

            val fragmentIds: List<String> = state.getStringArrayList(KEY_FRAGMENT_IDS)
            val fragmentStates: List<Fragment.SavedState> =
                    state.getParcelableArrayList(KEY_FRAGMENT_STATES)

            for ((index, id) in fragmentIds.withIndex()) {
                savedStates.put(id, fragmentStates[index])
            }

            for (key: String in state.keySet()) {
                if (key.startsWith(KEY_FRAGMENT_STATE)) {
                    val itemId = key.substring(KEY_FRAGMENT_STATE.length)

                    manager.getFragment(state, key)?.let {
                        it.setMenuVisibility(false)
                        fragmentsToItemIds.put(it, itemId)
                        itemIdsToFragments.put(itemId, it)
                    }
                }
            }

            unusedRestoredFragments.addAll(fragmentsToItemIds.keys)
        }
    }

    private fun Fragment.destroy() {
        if (currentTransaction == null) {
            // We commit the transaction later
            @SuppressLint("CommitTransaction")
            currentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction()
        }

        val itemId = fragmentsToItemIds.remove(this)
        itemIdsToFragments.remove(itemId)
        if (itemId != null) {
            savedStates.put(itemId, manager.saveFragmentInstanceState(this))
        }

        currentTransaction!!.remove(this)
    }

    private companion object {
        const val KEY_FRAGMENT_IDS = "fragment_keys_"
        const val KEY_FRAGMENT_STATES = "fragment_states_"
        const val KEY_FRAGMENT_STATE = "fragment_state_"
    }
}
```

And the Java piece:

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A PagerAdapter whose {@link #setPrimaryItem} is overridden with proper nullability annotations.
 */
public abstract class NullablePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container,
                               int position,
                               @Nullable Object object) {
        // `object` is actually nullable. It's even in the dang source code which is hilariously
        // ridiculous:
        // `mAdapter.setPrimaryItem(this, mCurItem, curItem != null ? curItem.object : null);`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have found a solution. This fixes the reordering issue of viewpager fragments, in case you are creating/modifying new tabs dynamically.

Use this class in place of FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java

```js
package android.support.v4.app;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class NewFragmentStatePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = "FragmentStatePagerAdapt";
    private static final boolean DEBUG = false;

    private final FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private FragmentTransaction mCurTransaction = null;

    private ArrayList<Fragment.SavedState> mSavedState = new ArrayList<Fragment.SavedState>();
    private ArrayList<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    private Fragment mCurrentPrimaryItem = null;

    public NewFragmentStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        mFragmentManager = fm;
    }

    /**
     * Return the Fragment associated with a specified position.
     */
    public abstract Fragment getItem(int position);

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
        if (container.getId() == View.NO_ID) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ViewPager with adapter " + this
                    + " requires a view id");
        }
    }
    public void destroyItemState(int position) {
        mFragments.remove(position);
        mSavedState.remove(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // If we already have this item instantiated, there is nothing
        // to do.  This can happen when we are restoring the entire pager
        // from its saved state, where the fragment manager has already
        // taken care of restoring the fragments we previously had instantiated.
        if (mFragments.size() > position) {
            Fragment f = mFragments.get(position);
            if (f != null) {
                return f;
            }
        }

        if (mCurTransaction == null) {
            mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        }

        Fragment fragment = getItem(position);
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Adding item #" + position + ": f=" + fragment);
        if (mSavedState.size() > position) {
            Fragment.SavedState fss = mSavedState.get(position);
            if (fss != null) {
                fragment.setInitialSavedState(fss);
            }
        }
        while (mFragments.size() <= position) {
            mFragments.add(null);
        }
        fragment.setMenuVisibility(false);
        fragment.setUserVisibleHint(false);
        mFragments.set(position, fragment);
        mCurTransaction.add(container.getId(), fragment);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) object;

        if (mCurTransaction == null) {
            mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        }
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Removing item #" + position + ": f=" + object
                + " v=" + ((Fragment)object).getView());
        while (mSavedState.size() <= position) {
            mSavedState.add(null);
        }
        mSavedState.set(position, fragment.isAdded()
                ? mFragmentManager.saveFragmentInstanceState(fragment) : null);
        mFragments.set(position, null);

        mCurTransaction.remove(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("ReferenceEquality")
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment)object;
        if (fragment != mCurrentPrimaryItem) {
            if (mCurrentPrimaryItem != null) {
                mCurrentPrimaryItem.setMenuVisibility(false);
                mCurrentPrimaryItem.setUserVisibleHint(false);
            }
            if (fragment != null) {
                fragment.setMenuVisibility(true);
                fragment.setUserVisibleHint(true);
            }
            mCurrentPrimaryItem = fragment;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
        if (mCurTransaction != null) {
            mCurTransaction.commitNowAllowingStateLoss();
            mCurTransaction = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return ((Fragment)object).getView() == view;
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        Bundle state = null;
        if (mSavedState.size() > 0) {
            state = new Bundle();
            Fragment.SavedState[] fss = new Fragment.SavedState[mSavedState.size()];
            mSavedState.toArray(fss);
            state.putParcelableArray("states", fss);
        }
        for (int i=0; i<mFragments.size(); i++) {
            Fragment f = mFragments.get(i);
            if (f != null && f.isAdded()) {
                if (state == null) {
                    state = new Bundle();
                }
                String key = "f" + i;
                mFragmentManager.putFragment(state, key, f);
            }
        }
        return state;
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
        if (state != null) {
            Bundle bundle = (Bundle)state;
            bundle.setClassLoader(loader);
            Parcelable[] fss = bundle.getParcelableArray("states");
            mSavedState.clear();
            mFragments.clear();
            if (fss != null) {
                for (int i=0; i<fss.length; i++) {
                    mSavedState.add((Fragment.SavedState)fss[i]);
                }
            }
            Iterable<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
            for (String key: keys) {
                if (key.startsWith("f")) {
                    int index = Integer.parseInt(key.substring(1));
                    Fragment f = mFragmentManager.getFragment(bundle, key);
                    if (f != null) {
                        while (mFragments.size() <= index) {
                            mFragments.add(null);
                        }
                        f.setMenuVisibility(false);
                        mFragments.set(index, f);
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Bad fragment at key " + key);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and use this to overide the method

```js
 @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
            if (getItemPosition(object) == POSITION_NONE) {
                destroyItemState(position);
            }
        }
```

Source : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36956111