# Android changing fragment order inside FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have ~20 fragments inside FragmentPagerAdapter that contains a list where it picks the fragments from so theres no recreation of fragments.

```
private List<TitledFragment> fragments;

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);

    this.fragments = new ArrayList<TitledFragment>();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    return fragments.get(i).getFragment();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
   return fragments.get(position).getTitle();
}

public synchronized List<TitledFragment> getFragments() {
    return fragments;
}


public synchronized void addFragment(TitledFragment fragment) {
    fragments.add(fragment);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

the FragmentPagerAdapter is set as adapter of ViewPager and after that I reorder the fragments(shuffling was just for test)

```
Collections.shuffle(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getFragments());
mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and for some reason only order of titles is being changed, even if its returning different fragment for getItem as the order is different. Why is this and how can I get around it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You also need to override [`getItemPosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getItemPosition%28java.lang.Object%29). By default, this function always returns `POSITION_UNCHANGED`, so that when you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, the adapter assumes that all of the fragments are still in the same position. (It does not call `getItem()` again, since it thinks all of the necessary fragments are already created.) Your new `getItemPosition()` should return the new position of each fragment after shuffling.

An easy hack is to always return `POSITION_NONE`, and then the adapter will just discard all of the existing fragments, and recreate them in their correct positions when calling `getItem()`. Of course, this is not efficient, and has the additional drawback that the current fragment being viewed may change. However, since there may possibly be some bugs in reordering the fragments - see [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12510404/reorder-pages-in-fragmentstatepageradapter-using-getitempositionobject-object) - the `POSITION_NONE` approach may be the safest method.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is a non-optimal answer. Returning `POSITION_NONE` from `int getItemPosition(Object)` just destroys any hope of efficient fragment management, requiring all fragnents to be reinstantiated. It also ignores another problem. The FragmentPageAdapter keeps a cached copy of the Fragment in the FragmentManager, and it looks for those copies when instantiating a new Fragment. If it finds what it thinks is a matching fragment, the `public Fragment getItem(int)` method is not called and the cached copy is used.

For example, lets say pages 0 and 1 are loaded, there will be cached fragments tagged with 0 and 1 in the FragmentManager. Now a page is inserted at index 0 (don't forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`), the old index 0 becomes 1 and 1 becomes 2 (this is signalled using the method `public int FragmentPageAdapter.getItemPosition(Object)`). For item 0 POSITION_NONE was returned (as it is the new position), so the method `public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int)` is called for position 0:

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    if (mCurTransaction == null) {
        mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    }

    final long itemId = getItemId(position);

    // Do we already have this fragment?
    String name = makeFragmentName(container.getId(), itemId);
    Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
    if (fragment != null) {
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Attaching item #" + itemId + ": f=" + fragment);
        mCurTransaction.attach(fragment);
    } else {
        fragment = getItem(position);
        ...
```

See what happens, a cached Fragment is found for position 0, and the fragment you wanted in position 1 is now in position 0, the fragment you wanted in position 2 is now in position 1 and in position 2 you get a new fragment returned by FragmentPageAdapter.getItem(int) that is a duplicate of position 1.

How to solve this? I have seen many suggestions on SO including:

1. Always return POSITION_NONE from  FragmentPageAdapter.getItemPosition() https://stackoverflow.com/a/7386616/2351246 - this answer ignores efficiciency and memory management (and will eventually not work without clearing out cached fragments)
2. Tracking the fragment tags https://stackoverflow.com/a/12104399/2351246, this relies on implementation details that could change.
3. And worst of all use magic by reverse engineering the  FragmentPageAdapter implementation https://stackoverflow.com/a/13925130/2351246, this is just horrible.

There is no need to ruin the memory management or to track the internal implementation details of `FragmentPagerAdapter`. The missing detail in all the answers is that a FragmentPagerAdapter that wants to **reorder fragments** must implement the method `public long getItemId(int position)` also:

```
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return System.identityHashCode(fragments.get(position));
    }
```

This provides a non position based ID that can be used to look up the correct fragment in the FragmentManager cache even if it moves page.